# using mapbox to lit element with bundler rollup

Tags: typescript, mapbox, rollup, lit

I would using mapbox on lit element with bundler rollup,I get the following error while importing

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js' does not provide an export named 'Map' (at page-home.ts:3:9)
```

The way I imported it :

```
import {Map} from 'mapbox-gl';
```

link config rollup :
[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xesoha/edit?js)

Is it possible to use Mapbox in Lit element with bundler rollup ?